# Disable drivers through command line

Tags: migration-assistant

I don't know if this question had been asked before, cause I am new here. This is the case: I have a friend who has a server with Windows Server 2008 R2. He wanted me to create an image of that server and install it in another different server. Obviously if I image the new one with that image it will blue screen due to different hardware configuration. I was wondering if it is possible to disable all Windows drivers to make windows start with the purpose to upgrade to the latest Windows Server. The purpose of the new server is to use it in case the actual one fail, to swap servers. Data is in an external drive so he wants to swap servers, connect the drive in new server and keep running his office in a short time. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless the original server image was set up with Sysprep, it is unlikely to install properly on new hardware. Also make sure the license for the server was a retail license and not OEM. You cannot transfer OEM licenses to new hardware

Comment: Ty John for your support.  Much appreciated.